# How to align bootstrap 4 navbar in a single row, when collapsed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make *navbar* in a **single row** of *non-collapsed items* with the *navbar-toggler* button, when **collapsed**
[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/c1c687Ld/). However it splits into multiple rows after collapsed. How to make it in a single row?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
 <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

Comment: Can you clarify want you want "collapsed"? Do you want all of the items in the toggle mobile menu, or only some? Do you want the items to remain horizontal in the toggled mobile menu too?

Comment: i want `Logout` and `Settings` non collapsed, with collapsible `Home`, `Features` and `Pricing` in the toggle button

Comment: Ok, but which items are horizontal vs. vertical?

Comment: i have done see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t36scr62/) but failed to move `Settings` and `Logout` to right-side in large screens